# Avoiding line breaks in HTML for design purposes

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap with HTML to build a website. Several times I have found myself putting in line breaks 
 in the code for design purposes. This feels n00by and I want to find a better way to do this.

Example 1: I have a navbar at the top of my page. I include it in every new page. When I type something in a page it doesn't show because it's behind the navbar and I need 3 line breaks for this on every page.

Example 2: I have a layout with a sidebar and a center page. I want them both to go a little below the screen size even if there are few links in the sidebar or little content in the center page. I feel like there is a better way than to include line breaks on every page... I also want them to be aligned.

So, please help me with ideas on how you would normally solve these problems.

Comment: If you add a jsfiddle people could better help you. That said, make use of css! Add margins and padding to help move your text around

Comment: +1 for creeating a JSFiddle, and using CSS. For example #1, it really depends on your markup, but you're going to want to do something like .content {margin-top: 50px;}

Answer (score 1):

It's generally a good idea to separate your presentation from the actual content, so these should be done using [CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS).  (In particular, there are *surprisingly few* situations where you want to use line breaks: [addresses, poems](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br).)  There is a *lot* of neat stuff you can do with CSS but there's no way I can explain this in one answer, so consider reading a [tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started) or a book on it.

Your Example 1 can be solved by adding a `margin-top` to the element that contains your content:

```
.content {
    margin-top: 100px; /* equal to the height of the navbar */
}
```

Example 2 is a bit more complex, but you can use `@media` queries to adjust the widths of the elements depending on the size of the user's screen:

```
.sidebar {
    width: 200px; /* normal width */
}
@media (max-width: 500px) {
    .sidebar {
        width: 100px; /* reduced width for smaller screens */
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for saying what I was thinking. I was too lazy to make a real answer :)